# What the difference preamble and access code?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

gnuradio packetize using access code for start sync packet, but another example attach the preamblee, so what the differences preamble and access code ?

Comment: Don't use the packet encoder/decoder. They don't work. That's why they are in the "deprecated" category.

Comment: (I don't know the answer to your question by heart, I'd need to read the source code just as much as you'd do – since these blocks are deprecated, I'm not going to do this for you)

Comment: It seems to me that your comments should be an answer, @MarcusMüller.

Comment: it's not an answer, sadly.

Comment: iam using example file packetize on folder example/digital/packet. In Transmitter side(packet_tx.grc) header activated access code, but in Receiver side(packet_rx.py) call preamble that was determined before for sync signal. The value of preamble and access code is same, and my question is what the differences preamble and access code :)) @MarcusMüller

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question by heart, I'd need to read the source code just as much as you'd do – since these blocks are deprecated, I'm not going to do this for you